# How to change frame color in tkinter python when button is pressed?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

Is there any way to have the frame background color change when I press a button?

Comment: this can be answered by reading a little documentation and/or working through a tkinter tutorial.

Comment: yest, there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways one could do that simply by setting `frame['bg']` to either a hexadecimal RGB value in the format of `'#000000'` or to [named color references](https://wiki.tcl.tk/37701). Below is a `button` that changes a `frame`'s background color to `'medium sea green'`:

```
import tkinter as tk


def change_bg(widget):
    widget['bg'] = 'medium sea green'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, height=100, width=100)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Paint")
    button['command'] = lambda wgt=frame : change_bg(wgt)

    frame.pack()
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

---

Below is an example in which a `frame` cycles its background color through RGB format:

```
import tkinter as tk


def cycle(event, widget):
    if widget['bg'][0] != '#':
        widget['bg'] = "#000000"
    else:
        widget['bg'] = '#' + str(int(widget['bg'][1:]) + 1).zfill(6)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, height=200, width=200)
    frame.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, widget=frame: cycle(event, widget))
    frame.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried both of these and I get the error: ```RGBsliders.py", line 21, in update
    preview['bg'] = hex
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment```

Comment: @LegacyCoding verify that `preview` is what you think it is.

Comment: Preview is the name of my frame. I did some more research and found it to be a ttk/tk issue. To fix it i had to use ```import tkinter as tk  :  tk.Frame()``` instead of ```from tkinter import *  :   Frame()```. I dont get why this works but it did so im just gona leave it. (I only used  : to seperate lines)

Comment: @LegacyCoding If you import multiple scripts without the `as` keyword, classes may be overwritten by the next import. In this case you were probably overwriting tk's Frame class with another class.